# if DEBUG filepaths in debug and prod. mode

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read file from specific path location. That location has different disk letter and directory structure on localserver and online server.

So I want by default to set filepath to meet my online server disk and when I'm debugging application to work with local filepath.

I tried with this

```
private const string _configurationFilePath = @"E:\web\mysite\";   
#if DEBUG
enter code here
_configurationFilePath = @"D:\mywebprj\mysite\";
#endif
```

I'm getting error message already contains definition for _configurationPath

Is there better way to this without using configuration files and other manually typed solutions?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#if DEBUG #else #endif`

```
#if DEBUG
    private const string a = @"d:\";
#else
    private const string a = @"e:\";
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `private const string` so it cannot be modified. Write you code like this:

```
#if !DEBUG
    private const string _configurationFilePath = @"E:\web\mysite\";   
#endif
#if DEBUG
enter code here
    private const string _configurationFilePath = @"D:\mywebprj\mysite\";
#endif
```

BTW much better idea is to store this path in configuration instead of harcoding it.

Answer (score 2):

One better solution. You can use copy msbuild task in afterbuild section of project file.

You can create multiple app.config according to solution configuration name using nomenclature app.$(configuration).config. Example: app.Debug.config. app.Release.config, etc.

And then use msbuild copy task to copy only one app config file to $(OutDir) as MyProject.exe.config.